# Android dnsjava NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Duration;

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, dnsjava

I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError with my app. I'm using dnsjava, okhttp3 and retrofit. My min API is 19.

I read that the java.time package was added in API 26. Does this mean that I can't use dnsjava for Android API lower than 26? Or does something else cause this error (proguard for example)? Can using an older dnsjava version help? I couldn't find any information about the minimum API of dnsjava.

Edit: I found this on the dnsjava Github page.

> Migrating from version 2.1.x to v3
>
> Methods using java.util.Date are deprecated. Use the new versions with
> java.time.Instant or java.time.Duration instead

So does this mean I can use version 2.1.x?

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: de.url.myproject, PID: 10723
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Duration;
    at org.xbill.DNS.ExtendedResolver.<clinit>(ExtendedResolver.java)
    at org.xbill.DNS.Lookup.refreshDefault(Lookup.java:1)
    at org.xbill.DNS.Lookup.<clinit>(Lookup.java:1)
    at org.xbill.DNS.Lookup.getDefaultResolver(Lookup.java)
    at de.url.myproject.MyDNS.init(MyDNS.java)
    at de.url.myproject.MyDNS.lookup(MyDNS.java)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:19)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:19)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:19)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:19)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.e(StreamAllocation.java)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:10)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:10)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:103)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:103)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:27)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:27)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:7)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:2)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:12)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.a(RealCall.java)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.Duration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.url.myproject-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.url.myproject-1/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/de.url.myproject-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 22 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/de.url.myproject-1/split_config.xxhdpi.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(DexFile.java)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:373)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:113)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:78)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:359)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeElements(DexPathList.java:323)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:263)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:126)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:58)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:540)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:573)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1990)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:799)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.<init>(ContextImpl.java:2217)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5547)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

My code:

```
package de.url.myproject;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import org.xbill.DNS.Address;
import org.xbill.DNS.ExtendedResolver;
import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;
import org.xbill.DNS.Resolver;
import org.xbill.DNS.SimpleResolver;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Dns;

public class MyDNS implements Dns {

    private static final String LIVE_API_HOST = "api.myproject.de";
    private static final String LIVE_API_IP = "12.345.67.890";

    private boolean mInitialized;
    private InetAddress mLiveApiStaticIpAddress;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<InetAddress> lookup(@NonNull String hostname) throws UnknownHostException {
        // I'm initializing the DNS resolvers here to take advantage of this method being called in a background-thread managed by OkHttp
        init();
        try {
            return Collections.singletonList(Address.getByName(hostname));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // fallback to the API's static IP
            if (LIVE_API_HOST.equals(hostname) && mLiveApiStaticIpAddress != null) {
                return Collections.singletonList(mLiveApiStaticIpAddress);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        if (mInitialized) return; else mInitialized = true;

        try {
            mLiveApiStaticIpAddress = InetAddress.getByName(LIVE_API_IP);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.w("DNS", "Couldn't initialize static IP address");
        }

        try {
            // configure the resolvers, starting with the default ones (based on the current network connection)
            Resolver defaultResolver = Lookup.getDefaultResolver();
            // use Google's public DNS services
            Resolver googleFirstResolver = new SimpleResolver("8.8.8.8");
            Resolver googleSecondResolver = new SimpleResolver("8.8.4.4");
            // also try using Amazon
            Resolver amazonResolver = new SimpleResolver("205.251.198.30");
            Lookup.setDefaultResolver(new ExtendedResolver(new Resolver[]{
                    defaultResolver, googleFirstResolver, googleSecondResolver, amazonResolver}));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.w("DNS", "Couldn't initialize custom resolvers");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble yet,not i use the "minidns" to replaced,It's friendly to android.

implementation 'de.measite.minidns:minidns:0.1.7'

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved it by adding `try ... catch`. If you want to keep the function going, you can switch to another downloading method when Android is under 1.8.

```
try {

            if (client == null) {
                notifyFail("System does not support")

            } else {

                val result = client?.startStreamTranscription(getRequest(22000), AudioStreamPublisher(FileInputStream(File(fileName))), getResponseHandler())
                if (NetworkUtils.isAvailable(BaseApp.context)) {
                    result?.get()
                    client?.close()
                }

            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logee { "startTrans ${e.message}" }
        }
```

Another way is that you can copy the whole time package into local:

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from using SMS-style abbreviations in Stack Overflow posts. Use the proper (full) English words.